# how to check duplicate record DB mongodb? using yii2

Tags: php, file, import, yii2

**My Action**

```
if(Yii::$app->request->post()){
            $eventName = Event::find()->select(['Event_name'])->from('Event')->where(['Calendar' => ['4']])->all();
            $model->file = $model->uploadFile($model,'file');
            $fh = fopen($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'], "r");
            while (($row = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ","))!= FALSE)
            {   
                $model = new Event();
                $model->Event_name = $row[0];
                $model->Discription =  $row[1];
                foreach ($eventName as $value){
                if($value->Event_name != $model->Event_name){
                    $model->save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return $this->render('index', ['model' => $model,'value'=> $query]);
```

i want to check duplicate record in my db (mongodb) and csv file. 
if condition true model will save data to db 
else  delete old data and save new data to db